# Button doesn't update with new inputDate from Ionic Date Picker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, ionic-framework

I need a date picker for my Ionic app. I am trying to use this one as it seems popular:

> https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker

I have tried to follow the tutorial, and it works well, but the date button doesn't update based on the date selection. How can I make it update?

My code is below.

This is my controller:

```
app.controller('EnterDatapointCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

  $scope.datepickerObject = {
    titleLabel: 'Title',  //Optional
    inputDate: new Date(),  //Optional
    callback: function (val) {  //Mandatory
        datePickerCallback(val);
    }
  };

  var datePickerCallback = function (val) {
    if (typeof(val) === 'undefined') {
      console.log('No date selected');
    } else {
      console.log('Selected date is : ', val)
    }
  };
});
```

This is my template:

```
<ion-view view-title="New Sales">
  <ion-content class="padding">

    <ionic-datepicker input-obj="datepickerObject">
      <button class="button button-block button-positive"> {{datepickerObject.inputDate | date:'dd - MMMM - yyyy'}}</button>
    </ionic-datepicker>

    <div class="list list-inset">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Amount" ng-model="data.amount">
      </label>
    </div>

    <button class="button button-block button-stable" ng-click="save()">Save</button>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a line to the callback. I didn't understand that I was supposed to modify the callback function.

> `$scope.datepickerObject.inputDate = val;`

```
app.controller('EnterDatapointCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

  $scope.datepickerObject = {
    titleLabel: 'Title',  //Optional
    inputDate: new Date(),  //Optional
    callback: function (val) {  //Mandatory
        datePickerCallback(val);
    }
  };

  var datePickerCallback = function (val) {
    if (typeof(val) === 'undefined') {
      console.log('No date selected');
    } else {
      console.log('Selected date is : ', val)
      $scope.datepickerObject.inputDate = val;
    }
  };

  $scope.save = function() {
    $state.go('confirm-datapoint');
  };
});
```